# Vibrate the device doesn't work as expected with QT android

Tags: android, qt, vibration

I have 2 issues with QT on Android when trying to vibrate the device with this piece of code:

1 - the device starts vibrate continously and the only way to stop it is to restart the device! I have to call vibrator.callMethod("cancel") to stop it programmatically.

2 - the device doesn't vibrate if the application is not focused on. Then when it is focused again, the device starts vibrate a long time and stops (it's like the vibrate requests were stacked and then executed one after the other)

I guess I have to deal with services to vibrate the device even when the mobile is idle or when there is no focus on the application.
I don't find any example to do it in a QT environment.
I would like to vibrate the device when receiving an alert from a server.

```
 void MainWindow::android_vibrate()
 {
      QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
      if ( activity.isValid() )
      {
          // This gets the string value of the VIBRATOR_SERVICE field.
          QAndroidJniObject serviceField = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField<jstring>("android/content/Context", "VIBRATOR_SERVICE");
          if ( serviceField.isValid() )
          {
              QAndroidJniObject vibrator = activity.callObjectMethod("getSystemService", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;",serviceField.object<jobject>());
              if ( vibrator.isValid() )
              {
                  // Note that vibrate takes a long and not an int as argument.
                  long duration = 200;
                  vibrator.callMethod<void>("vibrate", "(J)V", duration );
              }
          }
       }
  }
```